# how to apply permission class to particular method in class based views in Django-Rest Framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to apply permission only for "PUT" method not for "POST"

```
class Signup(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        something...something

    @authentication_classes((ExpiringTokenAuthentication,))
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
    def put(self, request, format=None):
        something...something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the HTTP method on your permission class `has_permission` method and apply your checks if it was PUT:

```
class ExpiringTokenAuthentication(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'PUT':
           # do it here


class Signup(APIView):
    permission_classes = (BlacklistPermission,)
```